# Scala - custom class constructors

Tags: android, scala, constructor

I have a simple question but couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I have the following java code. FrameLayout is an android class that has 2 constructors:

```
public class FrameLayout {
  public FrameLayout(Context context){ //do something
  }
  public FrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){ //do something
  }
  ....
}

public class ClassA extends FrameLayout{
  public ClassA(Context c){ 
      super(c);
      callSomeInitMethod();
  }

  public ClassA(Context a, AttributeSet b){ 
        super(a,b);
        callSomeInitMethod();
  }
}
```

I have the following scala code but it's not the same as the default constructor doesn't call the 'callSomeInitMethod()':

```
abstract class BaseComponent(context : Context, attrs : AttributeSet)
                                 extends FrameLayout(context, attrs) {
  def this(context : Context) = {
    this(context, null)
    callSomeInitMethod()
  }
```

How to I implement this in Scala?.  Thanks!.

Comment: There is a part of your example which can't be done in Scala: two constructors calling different parent class constructors. In Scala, only the primary constructor ever calls parent class constructor, and all secondary constructors can only call the primary constructor.

Comment: He/she probably already knows this, given that in his scala conversion he explictly passes null to the main constructor instead of calling a different base constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the call to `callSomeInitMethod` into the class body. This makes it part of the main constructor (and hence, of all the secondary constructors):

```
abstract class BaseComponent(context : Context, attrs : AttributeSet)
    extends FrameLayout(context, attrs) 
{
  callSomeInitMethod()

  def this(context : Context) = {
    this(context, null)
  }
}
```